# How to continue running SWT application even after switching user account in Windows or Any other OS?

Tags: swt, backgroundworker, background-process

Suppose If I have a User account "A" and "B" in Windows(or Any other OS). And I'm running a long running process through SWT Application in the user account "A". If I lock the user account "A" and switch to "B", I want my process to be continue running. Also the process should continue running if I just lock my computer and went away.

How can we achieve this ?

Comment: SWT doesn't provide anything to deal with this, it is just the same as any other application in this respect.